# How can I get Intellij Community Edition to play nicely with GWT UiBinder?

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea, uibinder

First- I am not using the EAP version, which I understand has built-in support.  This is not a viable option.

I am getting XML validation errors on simple things like HTML  elements and ui:field="" attributes.  What can i tell Idea to make it handle these things correctly?  To my "Resources" settings, I already added the uibinder and client.ui XSD's, as well as gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent.

Answer (score 2):

GWT is [not supported](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) in the Community Edition.